# How to generate core dump file without crash/segfault for c/c++ program

Tags: c++, gdb

The system will generate a core dump file when a c/c++ program crash/segfault, and then we can use the gdb to check the backtrace per the core dump file. 
But in some cases, the program may not crash, but we also want to check the backtrace, ie, we want to generate a core dump file for the program. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use: https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker It works pretty well.

Comment: Why not to set a breakpoint and see backtrace? Why do you want to generate a core dump for this?

Comment: `raise(SIGTRAP)`

Comment: Or better, if you want a bactracke at a specific place without killing the process `if (fork() == 0) raise (SIGTRAP);`

Comment: @Oliv: `SIGTRAP` can be caught. `SIGKILL` cannot, see [signal(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (assuming a Linux system)

Comment: @BiaoCao: **on which operating system?** Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62234013/edit) your question to improve it!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That can easily be fixed with signal mask. I prefer SIGTRAP because it is intended for that: break point and core dump.

Answer (score 2):

> in some cases, the program may not crash, but we also want to check the backtrace, ie, we want to generate a core dump file for the program,

Your "i.e." does not follow: you can trivially generate a backtrace *without* generating a core dump.

Since your question has gdb tag, I assume you want to do this from *outside* of the program itself (there are ways to do this from *inside* of the program as well).

Many systems have a `backtrace` GDB wrapper, but you can do this with "vanilla" GDB like so:

```
gdb --batch -q -p $PID -ex 'where' -ex 'quit'
gdb --batch -q -p $PID -ex 'thread apply all where' -ex 'quit'
```

Replace `$PID` with actual process id you want to get stack trace for.
Use the second form for multithreaded programs if you want stack traces for all threads.

If you really do want to save the core without killing the program, GDB can do that with the [gcore](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/gcore-man.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

> But in some cases, the program may not crash, but we also want to check the backtrace

For such cases, **I recommend using a good backtracing library**. With Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) (for C++ code compiled on Linux with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging information, e.g. compiled with `g++ -O1 -g2 -Wall`), you'll get a good one.

I'm happily using it at runtime, in my [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (for example, see its [issue#25](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/issues/25)).  And of course [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) also uses it (to report cleverly about fatal errors).

Of course, [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) has [backtrace](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) functions too. On Linux, you could combine them with [dladdr(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr1.3.html).

> we want to generate a core dump file

On Linux, I would recommend using [gcore(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) for that purpose.

Of course, core dumping can be disabled at runtime on Linux. See [core(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) and [setrlimit(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html). And some memory might not be dumped, see [mmap(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [elf(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

PS. On non Linux systems (e.g. [FreeBSD](https://freebsd.org/) or [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)), etc...), `gdb` behavior and `core` dumps could be quite different....

Comment: On linux, what is dumped can be customized with /proc/pid/coredump_filter

Comment: Yes, as explained in [core(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) mentioned in answer above